# Trying to create a program that simulates rolling 500 dice and showing the number of ones, twos, uptill sixs, in the form of stars

Tags: java

```
public class looptests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randGen = new Random();
        int seedValue = 0;
        randGen.setSeed(seedValue);

        int i;          // Loop counter iterates numRolls times
        int numRolls;   // User defined number of rolls
        int numOnes = 0;
        int numTwos = 0;
        int numThrees = 0;
        int numFours = 0;
        int numFives = 0;
        int numSixes = 0;   // Tracks number of 6s found

        int diceOne; // Dice 1 values
        int diceTwo;
        int totalRolls = 0;  // Sum of dice values

        numRolls = 500;

        // Roll dice numRoll times
        if  (numRolls >= 500);

            for (i = 0; i < numRolls; i++) {
                diceOne = randGen.nextInt(6);
                diceTwo = randGen.nextInt(6);

                totalRolls = diceOne + diceTwo;

                if (totalRolls == 1) {
                    numOnes = numOnes + 1;
                }
                if (totalRolls == 2) {
                    numTwos = numTwos + 1;
                }
                if (totalRolls == 3) {
                    numThrees = numThrees + 1;
                }
                if (totalRolls == 4) {
                    numFours = numFours + 1;
                }
                if (totalRolls == 5) {
                    numFives = numFives + 1;
                }
                if  (totalRolls == 6) {
                    numSixes = numSixes + 1;
                }
            }
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 6) {

            // Print statistics on dice rolls
            System.out.println("One (" + numOnes + ")");
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how far I reached, and I am having a couple of issues, number one, this is not randomized, I get the same numbers over and over, secondly, I am not managing to display the "*" to reflect the number of how many times i got a one or two. 
example:

One (65): *****************************************************************

Two (80): ********************************************************************************

Three (86): **************************************************************************************

Four (107): ***********************************************************************************************************

Five (91): *******************************************************************************************

Six (71): ***********************************************************************

Answer (score 2):

You get the same numbers because you set the same seed to Random instance. Generate random seed by, for example, Math.random() or don't set the seed at all.

To print stars, you can just use loop and print stars by one:

```java
System.out.print("One (" + numOnes + ")");
for (int i = 0; i < numOnes; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: That worked for random numbers, thanks! any tips on showing the corresponding number of stars for each generated number?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `java.security.SecureRandom` rather than `java.util.Random` it is more cryptographically secure.

I prefer this way of generating stars:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(pad('*', 25));
}

private static String pad(final char padChar, final int count) {
    final char[]          pad = new char[count];
    Arrays.fill          (pad, padChar);
    return String.valueOf(pad);
}
```

It's more efficient & more flexible.